# Create Listview C#

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I need to create a list view programmatically. This list view is populated from a sql server. The labels have their bindings set via a observable collection Shooters. I need this list view to change the number of columns based on a variable called rounds. Everything works as intended but this line of code causes the UI to be messed up.

```
var con = new CustomViewCell(Rounds);
          var connect = await con.GetCellLayout(Rounds); // Returns a grid

          var ShooterDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
          {
              return new ViewCell { View = connect }; // assigns grid to the viewcell view
          });
```

I get duplicate rows with the same information and other rows are missing their labels. Microsoft called this an inline Data Template. Image below in hyperlink

[bad ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTvxX.png)

The second options they say is to do it like so..

```
ShooterListView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(new Typeof(CustomViewCell));
```

When done this way The UI Looks normal. The problem though is that I cant pass the rounds variable to the customviewcell which determines which function to use to set all the columns.

Here is the exact same grid but done through typeof(CustomViewCell)

[Good UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2A4Dx.png)

In both cases I use the exact same grid layout design the only difference is I use inline code to create the data template and then a typeof(customViewCell) how can I get the inline code to not cause such a weird layout design since I cant pass a variable to typeof(CustomViewCell).

Grid code attached below

```
public async Task<Grid> Get_Round_7_Cell()
        {
            var column1 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column2 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(15, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column3 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column4 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column5 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column6 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column7 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column8 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };
            var column9 = new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(10, GridUnitType.Star) };

            var smallfont = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label));

            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                PaddingLeft = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                PaddingLeft = new Thickness(60, 0, 0, 0);
            }


            if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Tablet || Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
            {
                PaddingRight = new Thickness(0, 0, 20, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                PaddingRight = new Thickness(0, 0, 60, 0);
            }

            var shooterlabel = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start, FontSize = smallfont, Padding = PaddingLeft };
            shooterlabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Shooter_Name"));
            var team_name_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            team_name_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Team_Name"));
            var round1_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round1_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_1"));
            var round2_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round2_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_2"));
            var round3_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round3_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_3"));
            var round4_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round4_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_4"));
            var round5_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round5_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_5"));
            var round6_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center, FontSize = smallfont };
            round6_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_6"));
            var round7_label = new Label() { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End, FontSize = smallfont, Padding = PaddingRight };
            round7_label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Round_7"));

            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column1);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column2);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column3);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column4);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column5);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column6);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column7);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column8);
            grid2.ColumnDefinitions.Add(column9);

            grid2.Children.Add(shooterlabel, 0, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(team_name_label, 1, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round1_label, 2, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round2_label, 3, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round3_label, 4, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round4_label, 5, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round5_label, 6, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round6_label, 7, 0);
            grid2.Children.Add(round7_label, 8, 0);

            grid.Children.Add(boxview);
            grid.Children.Add(grid2);


            return grid;
        }
```

Comment: use CollectionView, not ListView.  CV does rely on the Cell concept

Comment: I meant "does not rely on the Cell concept"

Comment: Ill give it a shot. the only other solution I have is to make 10 CustomCellViews for each round. not exactly friendly. Hopefully collection view will work thanks!

Comment: @BrianPalmer Seems that you have solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solution below. Not the best but its getting the job done. I never could get inline DataTemplate to work so I had to make custom view cells for each round and call them based on what Rounds value was.

```
public async Task<ListView> SetShooterListView(int Rounds)
        {

            var shooterlistview = new ListView() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill };

            var headergrid = Rounds == 1 ? await Get_Round_1() : Rounds == 2 ? await Get_Round_2() : Rounds == 3 ? await Get_Round_3() : Rounds == 4 ? await Get_Round_4() : Rounds == 5 ? await Get_Round_5() : Rounds == 6 ? await Get_Round_6() : Rounds == 7 ? await Get_Round_7() : Rounds == 8 ? await Get_Round_8() : Rounds == 9 ? await Get_Round_9() : await Get_Round_10();

            var viewcellgrid = Rounds == 1 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_1_View)) : Rounds == 2 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_2_View)) : Rounds == 3 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_3_View)) : Rounds == 4 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_4_View)) : Rounds == 5 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_5_View)) : Rounds == 6 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_6_View)) : Rounds == 7 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_7_View)) : Rounds == 8 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_8_View)) : Rounds == 9 ? new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_9_View)) : new DataTemplate(typeof(Round_10_View));



            


            shooterlistview.Header = headergrid;


            shooterlistview.ItemTemplate = viewcellgrid;
            return shooterlistview;
           

        }
```